# Xamarin Forms app, HttpClient seemingly caching responses FOREVER

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm in the testing phase of my first Xamarin.Forms app, which relies heavily on the HttpClient to retrieve JSON data from a remote site. I've found that once a request has been made, the response seems to be cached and updated data is never retrieved. I'm initializing the HttpClient like this:

```
new HttpClient()
{
  Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0),
  DefaultRequestHeaders =
  {
    CacheControl = CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
    Pragma = { NameValueHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache")}
  }
}
```

Those request headers didn't seem to help at all. If I put one of the URLs in my browser, I get the JSON response with the updated data. The server side is setting a no-cache header as well.

Any idea how I can FORCE a fresh request each time? TIA. This testing is being done in an Android emulator, btw. I don't know yet whether the iOS build is behaving similarly.

Comment: Are you using the AndroidHttpHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the [modernhttpclient nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/), and implement your android code like:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
```

This code works on both android, iOS and/or code in a PCL. Basically this nuget package makes sure that you are using the latest platform optimizations for the HttpClient. For Android this is the *OkHttp*-package, for iOS this is *NSURLSession*.

This helps you prevent any of the quirks of the provided HttpClient class, and use the optimizations that the platform you're running offers you.

Issues like the one you show should no longer happen.

Comment: I don't like that you are recommending modernhttpclient. It doesn't work with HTTP/2 or SPDY. It pukes when talking to TLS 1.2 sites too.

Comment: I see. The Xamarin University instructors called this one of the best-practises during my training, so I can only assume that they are right. I have no experience with the things you describe, but we do have some fairly complex Xamarin apps in production with a fairly complex (but standard) Azure Web App backend. No problems there whatsoever.

Comment: I've had the same experience as @Cheesebaron . It all worked fine until some version of Mono started causing issues in Modern. App would just randomly crash if it lost connectivity and then retried queries once connectivity was restored. https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/issues/229   Removing modern completely fixed.  Currently to get around the "caching" thing I just add a '?cachebuster=<guid>' of a randomly generated guid. Which works great for locating specific requests in log files also :-)

Comment: Good tip @cachebuster!

Comment: adding a random queryparam was the first thing I tried, and it had no effect.  really bizarre behavior.
ModernHttpClient resolved this issue for me, though.  Many thanks to Erik.